# How dynamically load route in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Need on change search field - load route with params
/search/WORD, path of route, example, /search/:q

How is best way?

1. In template `{{input value=str}}` and in controller `this.transitionToRoute('search', this.store.find...)` . It require loading model in controller and duplicate to route `mode:function(){ return this.store.find...}`.
2. In controller call route by url `this.transitionToRoute('/search/' + str)`.

Else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For full refresh model need use refreshModel: true http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Answer (score 0):

why not use queryParams?

ie.,

```
Ember.controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['search'],
  search: null,
  doSomethingWhenSearchChanges: function() {
    // do something here...
  }.property('search')
});
```

Comment: Question: how load route without duplicate model?

Answer (score 0):

I would second Christopher's notion of using query params for this case. For such a solution, your route would be /search?q=WORD. This solution is much more flexible and adaptable, especially if you think your search parameters will change over time. For example, you might begin to search on a handful of different attributes, such as name, type, etc. If this occurs, your route would become /search?name=NAME&type=TYPE&etc=ETC.

If you absolutely must use a route as you've defined above, you can forward the param through the route using the model and serialize hooks. In coffeescript...

```
App.Router.map( ->

  @route('search', {path: '/search/:q'})

)

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: (params, transition) ->
    return { q: params.q }

  serialize: (model) ->
    return { q: model.get('q') }

})

App.SearchController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  strObserver: Ember.observer( ->
    @transitionToRoute('search', {q: @get('str')})
  ).observes('str')

})
```

Comment: Thank you, but question "how call route", not how define it. Model for this route is promise-model, not simple hash. How call route from controler or template without model, but with parameter - q.
Example, `transitionToRoute('search', {q:q})`

Comment: I updated my answer above to show how the controller and transitionToRoute call should look like. It is all dependent on how you set up the route.

Comment: My model in route as:
`model: function(params){ return this.store.find... }`
and when call route from controller, model not renew, because router take 2 parameter of transitionToRoute as model.